# How can I make '=' invoke a copy constructor in Perl?

Tags: perl, reference, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I know '=' can't be directly overloaded in Perl, but I want to be able to use '=' to call the copy constructor for one of my objects.

example:

```
my $object1 = Object->new('value' => 1);

# I want this to invoke the copy constructor of "$object1" instead of copying a reference
my $object2 = $object1;

# This should not modify "$object1"
$object2->set_value(12);

print $object1->get_value()."\n";
print $object2->get_value()."\n";
```

I want the output to be:

```
1
12
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Perl doesn't have constructors, copy or otherwise. Convention is to create a method called `clone`. // You can use [this](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload#Copy_Constructor) to do copy-on-write if your object is immutable except through overloaded operators. But that's not the case here.

Comment: I think I may make my object immutable except for overloaded operators.  That looks like it may be the most elegant approach.

Comment: Please treat Perl as Perl and not as C++. If you try to somehow enforce semantics you've used with other languages you will never have a happy relationship with the language.

Comment: Storable dclone?
http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html

Comment: In Perl, objects are implemented as blessed *references*, so they have reference semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone data you may use [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Clone-0.38/Clone.pm) module.

Example:

```
package Foo;
use parent 'Clone';
sub new { bless {}, shift }

package main;

my $obj = Foo->new;
my $copy = $obj->clone;
```